# Javascript Runtime error: syntax error, unrecognized expression:#

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

When below mentioned code runs in IE it gives me error initially: "Javascript Runtime error: syntax error, unrecognized expression:#" 
 but functionality that I want to focus is working fine.  It generates error for this line :

```
  $("#" + spanID).focus();
```

It does not produce any error in Chrome and Firefox browser. How I can handle it for IE?

Complete code:

```
 function closeLayer() {
    /// <summary>Function to hide layer.</summary>
    $(document).click(function (event) {

        $("#showLayer").dialog('close');

        $("#" + spanID).focus();
    });
}
```

I have declared spanID variable globally. Value of spanID will be "id1" or "id2".

```
function show(helpContentText) {

               //some code here

                var target = $(this);
                spanID = target[0].id;
}
```

Comment: There's no variable `spanID` in the function.

Comment: What is the *value* of `spanID`? I wonder if perhaps it already has a '#' in it..

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.